# & Operator Use in Python in Program

Tags: python

What does this `y & 3` do exactly and how does this `if..if y & 3..else` statement works ? Please anybody could explain ? Taken from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/day-of-the-programmer/leaderboard

```
y = int(input())
if y < 1918:
    ftext = "13.09.{}" if y & 3 else "12.09.{}"
elif y > 1918:
    ftext = "13.09.{}" if (y & 3) or (y % 400 and not y % 100) else "12.09.{}"
else:
    ftext = "26.09.{}"
print(y & 3)
print(ftext.format(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` operator does a bitwise AND between the operands.
y&3 masks the bits of y with the bits of 3.

Thus if y = 11110111  and 3 = 00000011
`y&3` will evaluate to 00000011

`"13.09.{}" if y & 3 else "12.09.{}"` checks the condition whether the last 2 bits of y are not both zero. if the last 2 bits of y are zero, the condition will become false.

Comment: Does that mean that its checking whether its divisible by 4 or not ??